# Subset data into ggplot2 works until I try to make it a function, then it only gives error bars with no data

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I have to make many graphs for a certain data set, so I wanted to make a function to make it more efficient.

I have a data frame mean.act.dt and I subset this to include only my genotypes (rows) of interest and only condition (column).

This works well until I tried to make it a function.

Is there some issue with the subsetting or am I not passing enough information to the function? What am I missing here?

The code that does work:

```
comp_actplot0<- ggplot(data=subset(mean.act.dt, genotype %in% c("Cirl Rescue / Def; UAS dTrp", "Cirl Rescue / TH 2M, Def; UAS dTrp", "Cirl Rescue / TH 2M, Def") & drug_condit %in% "0AMPH") , aes(x= t))+
  geom_line(aes(y= mean_act, color= genotype), size = 1.3) + 
  labs(title= "genotype_1", # CHANGE TITLE
       subtitle="Baseline", 
       caption=NULL,
       y = "Mean Activity (Counts/h)",
       color = NULL) +  # title and caption
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("dodgerblue2" = "Cirl Rescue / Def; UAS dTrp",
                                "black"= "Cirl Rescue / TH 2M, Def; UAS dTrp",
                                "grey48"="Cirl Rescue / TH 2M, Def"),
                      values = c("Cirl Rescue / Def; UAS dTrp"="dodgerblue2",
                                 "Cirl Rescue / TH 2M, Def; UAS dTrp"="black",
                                 "Cirl Rescue / TH 2M, Def"="grey48"))+
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean_act-sem, ymax=mean_act+sem), width=.1,
                position=position_dodge(0.05))+ # error bars
  theme(legend.position = c(.840,.841))+
  scale_x_hours(name = "Time", breaks = waiver(),
  minor_breaks = NULL, labels = waiver(), limits = hours(c(0,72)), #Or minor breaks = waiver()
  expand = waiver(), oob = scales::censor, na.value = NA_real_,
  position = "bottom", time_wrap = NULL, unit = "h")+ # set x axis scale
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1000))+ #adjust y axis
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust=0.5, size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.box.spacing = unit(.1, "in"),
        legend.box.just = "top")

  ggsave("filename_0.png", plot = comp_actplot0, device = "png", width = 7 , height = 5, units = "in")
```

The function that returns an empty plot with error bars only:

```
Comp_plot_0mM_5mM<- function(data.frame, genotype_1, genotype_2, genotype_3, x_limit, y_limit, filename_0){

 comp_actplot0<- ggplot(data=subset(data.frame, genotype %in% c(genotype_1, genotype_2, genotype_3) & drug_condit %in% "0AMPH") , aes(x= t))+
  geom_line(aes(y= mean_act, color= genotype), size = 1.3) + 
  labs(title= genotype_1, # CHANGE TITLE
       subtitle="Baseline", 
       caption=NULL,
       y = "Mean Activity (Counts/h)",
       color = NULL) +  # title and caption
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("dodgerblue2" = genotype_1,
                                "black"= genotype_2,
                                "grey48"=genotype_3),
                      values = c(genotype_1="dodgerblue2",
                                 genotype_2="black",
                                 genotype_3="grey48"))+
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean_act-sem, ymax=mean_act+sem), width=.1,
                position=position_dodge(0.05))+ # error bars
  theme(legend.position = c(.840,.841))+
  scale_x_hours(name = "Time", breaks = waiver(),
  minor_breaks = NULL, labels = waiver(), limits = hours(c(0,x_limit)), #Or minor breaks = waiver()
  expand = waiver(), oob = scales::censor, na.value = NA_real_,
  position = "bottom", time_wrap = NULL, unit = "h")+ # set x axis scale
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, y_limit))+ #adjust y axis
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust=0.5, size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.box.spacing = unit(.1, "in"),
        legend.box.just = "top")

  ggsave(filename_0, plot = comp_actplot0, device = "png", width = 7 , height = 5, units = "in")}
```

Expecting a graph with data on it and I get an empty graph with only error bars included.

Comment: Please post some of the data that you're using that reproduces the error, so that we can try it out ourselves.

Comment: `ggplot2` and `dplyr` and other packages in the `tidyverse` use a framework they call "tidy eval" to manage data masking. This necessitates changes when you use them for programming.  https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/sec-why-how.html#data-masking  https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/sec-up-to-speed.html

Comment: For using ggplot2 in packages and functions this link is very helpful: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#best-practices-for-common-tasks